# How to take past records and upcoming records using two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns, using this two columns i have to take the records from my DB,

1. Past EventId
2. Upcoming eventId

past eventId means which are the dates `(startDate & dueDate)` already completed, i want to take the records

upcoming eventId means which are the dates (startDate & dueDate) Not yet completed, i want to take the records

**events (table name)**

```
    eventId      name        startDate        dueDate

    1            A           2018-01-22       2018-01-22
    2            B           2018-01-26       2018-01-27
    3            C           2018-01-29       2018-01-31
```

I tried sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startDate >= '2018-01-30' AND dueDate <= '2018-01-30'
```

But nothing is happening,I don't how to write SQL query

**Expected past eventId**

```
eventId
  1
  2
```

**Expected upcoming eventId**

```
eventId
  3
```

Comment: `'2018-01-31' <= '2018-01-30'` is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Past Event:**

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startDate <= '2018-01-30' AND DueDate <= '2018-01-30'
```

**For Future Event:**

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE DueDate >= '2018-01-30'
```

Comment: You code `Future Event:` code is working fine , but `Past Event:` not working properly , it is returning eventId 1 & 2 & 3, but actual results is 1 & 2

Comment: @GaneshM, Try my Updated Answer

Comment: Mr@rst, answer is coming correct why bcz, upcoming events starting from `2017-01-29` upto `2017-01-31`, suppose today date `2017-01-30` means upcoming records should come that is eventId `3`

Comment: I can see this answer has already been accepted but I think @rst does make a valid point by quoting back the original question. This suggests to me also that both dates should be satisfied. If you'd said that startDate is always less than or equal to dueDate, then you'd be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99565b/5)

**Past Events**

```
SELECT id as 'eventId' FROM events WHERE startDate <= '2018-01-30' AND dueDate <= '2018-01-30';
```

**Future Event**

```
SELECT id as 'eventId' FROM events WHERE startDate >= '2018-01-30' AND dueDate >= '2018-01-30';
```

Comment: `Past Events` working fine , output is coming 1 & 2 but `Future Event` is not coming like out put count is `0` but actual count should come one `eventId 3`

Comment: According to your description and data the expected outcome of future events is 0 and not id 3 (i.e. 1). so everything is correct. Else you should update and correct your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    eventId
    ,case when dueDate < '2018-01-30' then 'Past' else case when duedate > '2018-01-30' then 'Future' END END
FROM Events
```

Comment: Your code is working , but i need separate query  like `Past Events`  separate query and `Future Event` separate query ,can you make like this please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming than '2018-01-30' is now

past events :

```
select * from events where '2018-01-30' <= startDate and dueDate <= '2018-01-30'
```

upcomming event

```
select * from events where '2018-01-30' <= startDate and '2018-01-30' <= dueDate
```

Comment: past events :  & upcomming event , Both are comming empty

Answer (score 0):

Your query will apply your where condition on each row so what it will return is a row which has start date greater than '2018-01-30' also due date less than '2018-01-30' which can not be possible. so you have to write two query and after that you can take Union of two query results.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startDate <= '2018-01-30'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startDate >= '2018-01-30' AND DueDate >= '2018-01-30'
```

This query will return a single column having past and future event.
But you won't be able to identify which event id is for past event and which event id is for future event.

To identify that you have to write two different query.

Answer (score 0):

For past eventId

```
select eventId from events where dueDate <= 2018-01-30
```

upcoming eventId

```
 select eventId from events where startDate >= 2018-01-30 or dueDate > 2018-01-30
```