# between in two columns not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table `events`

using this table i have to get the records between two dates and two columns in mysql,see below i mentioned my table format

```
eventId          startDate            dueDate

 1                2018-01-15          2018-01-17  
 2                2018-01-25          2018-01-25
 3                2018-01-11          2018-01-16
```

Suppose i want to take the records from `2018-01-14` into `2018-01-16` means actual results should come like below

> My Expected answer

```
eventId
 1
 3
```

> I tried like this but nothing is coming

```
 SELECT eventId FROM events WHERE startDate <= '2018-01-30' AND DueDate <= '2018-01-30'
```

> I am getting output

```
eventId
 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take past records and upcoming records using two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519807/how-to-take-past-records-and-upcoming-records-using-two-columns)

Comment: Why have post the same question for the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  between  the range you need eg:

```
 SELECT eventId 
 FROM events 
 WHERE startDate  BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16'
 AND DueDate BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16'
```

or you can also use different range for the two columns

for get the row with id = 3  you need   2018-01-11 and not 2018-01-14  for start  range

```
 SELECT eventId 
 FROM events 
 WHERE startDate  BETWEEN  '2018-01-11' AND  '2018-01-16'
 AND DueDate BETWEEN  '2018-01-11' AND  '2018-01-16'
```

or you could use an OR Condition for check just one of the two column from  14 to 16

```
 SELECT eventId 
 FROM events 
 WHERE startDate  BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16'
 OR  DueDate BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16'
```

Comment: i am using `date` datatype

Comment: answer update with a proper data range  ..and a condition for a check one of the two columsn

Comment: No, check my expected answer section, i need eventId `1 & 3`

Comment: I have update the answer with a 3th option (OR) and this shoudl retrieve  the row with id 1 and 3  ..

Comment: why because eventId 1 starting on `2018-01-15` into `2018-01-17` (search date 2018-01-14 into 2018-01-16 so eventId 1 available in this search dates and eventId 3 starting on `2018-01-11` into `2018-01-16` (search date 2018-01-14 into 2018-01-16 so eventId 3 also available in this search dates)

Comment: As in my last comment  the last code provided should return two records .. eventID 1 because startDate  BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16' and eventId 4 because DueDate BETWEEN  '2018-01-14' AND  '2018-01-16'

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want all events that 'are active' in a given date-range, e.g. between 2018-01-14 and 2018-01-16?

it helps to precisely formulate the 'what are my criteria' in natural language. i re-formulate what i think you mean:

give me all events that

- start before (or on) 2018-01-16
- end after (or on) 2018-01-14

it looks a bit weird - you have to compare event.startDate against range.endDate (and vice versa). but that is the correct check you need.
now it is easy to translate that to SQL:

```
SELECT eventId 
FROM events
WHERE startDate <= '2018-01-16'
  AND dueDate <= '2018-01-14'
```